CSS code that sets margin for content when printing but allows a full-page bacground-image
I'm creating a small webpage that also has a print function. I'm having some problems with page breaks and margins. If i set the margins in @page margin to 2cm the document prints fine, but the background-image doesn't fill the page. If I set the @page margin to 0cm the background fills the entire page, but page 2 and following pages doesn't have a top or bottom margin.
Is it possible to somehow set the @page margin to 2cm and stille have the background-image fill the entire page?
Here's my sample code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Print Background Image</title>
    <style>
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: A4;
                margin: 0;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            .print-background {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                background-image: url('images/background1.png');
                background-size: cover;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-position: center;
                z-index: -1;
            }

            .content {
                position: relative;
                margin: 2cm;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); /* Semi-transparent baggrund for at gøre teksten læsbar */
                padding: 1cm;
                border-radius: 5px;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="print-background"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Indhold til udskrivning</h1>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Indhold til udskrivning på side 2</h1>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Indhold til udskrivning på side 3</h1>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 3.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 3.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 3.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrundpå side 3.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Peter :)

Set the html and body height to 100% to make sure the full page is covered when printing.
Move the background image url from css to a <img> tag.
This should work with or without margins on @page.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Print Background Image</title>
    <style>
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: A4;
                margin: 0;
            }

            html,
            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }


            .print-background {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: -1;
            }
            .print-background img {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                object-fit: cover;
            }

            .content {
                position: relative;
                margin: 2cm;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
                padding: 1cm;
                border-radius: 5px;
                page-break-inside: avoid;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="print-background">
        <img src="https://cataas.com/cat?width=1920&height=1080" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Indhold til udskrivning</h1>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Indhold til udskrivning på side 2</h1>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 2.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Indhold til udskrivning på side 3</h1>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 3.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 3.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrund på side 3.</p>
        <p>Dette er noget tekst, der skal udskrives med en baggrundpå side 3.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>


Thank you for a quick reply! when I try this and look at the print previw in chrome there's no top margin on page 2 https://snipboard.io/lFjymk.jpg
